# Errors auto mounting google-drive-ocamlfuse

Tags: mount, hard-drive, google-chrome, fstab, automount

I recently set up google-drive-ocamlfuse so that I could use google drive from my desktop.  I followed the instructions on this website:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-mount-your-google-drive-on-linux-with-google-drive-ocamlfuse/

This worked but I then wanted it to automount my drive account to the ~/google-drive directory.  So after some more google searches I came across this website and followed it's instructions for editing the etc/fstab file:

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Automounting

Now, when I use the command mount ~/google-drive from the terminal it returns the following error:

```
[mntent]: line 1 in /etc/fstab is bad
```

Also, when I start up my computer, on the Xubuntu loading screen I have an error that looks something similar to:

Problem mounting /etc/fstab, press S to Skip or M to manually...

Here is the files that I saved as /usr/bin/gdfuse:

```
#!/bin/bash

su #USERNAME -l -c "google-drive-ocamlfuse -label $1 $*"
exit 0
```

(where #USERNAME was replaced with my actual username)

And here is my entire /etc/stab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=69922867-b952-4b03-b4dd-49147b516bbd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7e84ab94-0486-47e6-83c2-386278dc8a95 none            swap    sw              0 0
gdfuse#default  /home/#USERNAME/google-drive     fuse    uid=1000,gid=1000,user     0       0
```

(where, again, #USERNAME is replaced with my actual username)

Currently, when I restart the computer the /etc/fstab error message will be there.  If I let it sit it will not logon.  If I press 'S' it will logon.  Nothing seems wrong with it then, and the ~/google-drive directory has mounted properly and I can access my google drive files.  But when I restart, the same error will come up and it won't just log on with out me pressing S.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mount` to reconnect the remote Google Drive storage (essentially, a small cloud storage bucket) to the local mount point.  Instead, you must use the `google-drive-ocamlfuse` that you installed when you originally set this up.  Remove the `fstab` entry; it's invalid, as your error message shows.  Instead, include `google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/user/google-drive` (obviously, replace /home/user/google-drive with the actual path and folder you used when you first set up `google-drive-ocamlfuse`) in a file *that gets executed at startup*.  Use the full path, rather than the ~/ abbreviation, because the abbreviation may not be valid yet at the time your startup commands get executed.

No special privileges are needed; that is, you don't need to included `sudo` in the command line -- and once you've completed the initial setup, you won't need to relog to Google Drive again.  I haven't tested whether that remains true if you log your browser into a different Google account, but I suspect it does, because `google-drive-ocamlfuse` stores the connection tokens that were downloaded in the initial setup process.